# How to access rackspace calendar

Tags: java, rackspace

Is there any way available to access rackspace email calendar through java? Rackspace provides an API to access email but I am not able to find anything which allows me to access shared calendars for that user.

Thanks,
Farhan Zia

Answer (score 0):

The API does not provide an option for accessing the calendars of Rackespace Email users. For reference, the documentation for this API makes no mention of calendar access.

http://api-wiki.apps.rackspace.com/api-wiki/index.php/Customer_%28Rest_API%29